# Make react-select option unsearchable

Tags: react-select

I'm using react-select and have one option with a blank name and the value of `not set` and another with the name and value of `notification`. This means my options array looks something like this (though with many more options):

```
const options = [
  {
    label: '',
    value: 'not set'
  },
  {
    label: 'Notification',
    value: 'notification'
  }
];
```

Because of this, when users are looking for the notification option, they often just type `not` and then are shown the blank option.

I *do* want this option to show in the dropdown menu itself if someone is just thumbing through it (with arrow keys) but is there a way I can prevent certain options from showing in the search? Maybe a key I can include in the option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to use the props `filterOption` to achieve your goal. See more how to use it [here](https://react-select.com/props).

You can either decide to filter by `label` only instead of `value` or add a key for each searchable option like this:

```
const options = [
  {
    label: '',
    value: 'not set',
    searchable: false
  },
  {
    label: 'Notification',
    value: 'notification',
    searchable: true
  }
];

// your custom filterOption function
 filterOption = ({ label, value, data }, string) => {
    if (string && data.searchable) {
      return label.includes(string) || value.toString().includes(string);
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  };
```